# Open file from singleton

Tags: java, web

I'm trying to read a excel file in a singleton so it is loaded only once. 
The excel file and the singleton are in the same package but `getResourceAsStream` returns `null`.

What could I be missing ?

```
public static synchronized HSSFWorkbook getUniqueInstance(String fileStr) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        try {
            InputStream file = WBSingleton.class.getResourceAsStream(fileStr);
            sInstance = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sInstance;

}
```

Comment: this is not singleton. HSSFWorkbook can have many instances outside your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WBSingleton.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileStr);
```

You can also try

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(fileStr); 
InputStream name = url.openStream();
```

Comment: returns null as well